# Visual Studio WPF .NET Core doesn't provide ClickOnce publishing

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF .NET Core application (not .NET Framework) which I want to publish. But when I go to Build -> Publish -> Publish to folder, it only generates 6 files:

- MyApp.deps.json
- MyApp.dll
- MyApp.exe
- MyApp.pdb
- MyApp.runtimeconfig.dev.json
- MyApp.runtimeconfig.json

Is it possible to generate just the common setup.exe of ClickOnce? Somehow just sending these files and then starting the .exe file on the other PC doesn't work. I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.0. The program should be for Windows (10).

Steps:

1. Build -> Publish
2. A screen shows up, you can choose whether it should be published in a directory, to Azure or "Docker-Containerregistration". I chose "directory".
3. Then I chose a directory on my local computer (no webserver or something like this)
4. I clicked on "Publish" and the 6 files, which I mentioned above were built in this folder.

Problem: Sending just these files doesn't to another PC apparently doesn't work out, the .exe file won't start. On my computer, it works. Maybe it has something to do with an anti-virus program?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your detailed setting for each steps for me to analzye the issue? What the platform did your project target?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT I edited my post now, thanks!